# How to use R to separate data in space and time?

Tags: r, time, subset, latitude-longitude

My dataset includes positions (latitude/lat and longitude/lon) of many ships over a one-year period.

My data frame includes columns for the following fields: ship_ID, lat, lon, month, day, hour, & ship_speed.

There are hundreds of rows for each ship, and each represents the ship's location (lat, lon) at a different time and/or on a different day.

I am new to R and would like to use loops to:

1-Split the data into 0.05° lon x 0.05° lat gridcells using the following arrays of lat & lons: my_lat_range =seq(45.5, 51.5, by=0.05), and my_lon_range =seq(-66, -57, by=0.05).

2-Next, split the data by day, resulting in a 3D data frame (lon, lat, day)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you show few rows of the example data and expected output based on that

Comment: You don't need a loop. Use the `cut` function to group your data by lat, lon, and time ranges. For example: `df$lat.grp = cut(df$lat, breaks=seq(45.5, 51.5, 0.05))`